# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '('

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am trying to query to insert in a table and i keep getting this message:

The Query is:

```
INSERT INTO A_USER(PK,status,login_id,HASHBYTES('md5', password),fk_role,last_update_ts,last_update_by,created_by)
VALUES (2,1,'abc', 'abc',2,'3/15/2012 12:21:46 PM','abc','abc')
```

Comment: Look at your query. Anything seem out of place? Anything seem inconsistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with this line `HASHBYTES('md5', password)`, you want to use the `HASHBYTES` in the `VALUES` area of your `INSERT`.

```
INSERT INTO A_USER
(
    PK
    ,status
    ,login_id
    ,[password] -- change to the name of your column.
    ,fk_role
    ,last_update_ts
    ,last_update_by
    ,created_by
)
VALUES 
(
    2
    ,1
    , 'abc'
    ,HASHBYTES('md5', 'abc') -- place your password to be hashed where 'abc' is.
    ,2
    ,'3/15/2012 12:21:46 PM'
    ,'abc'
    ,'abc'
)
```

Comment: yeah I got away with this, but now getting this error...it is giving another error now...Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 The name "password" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: I just updated my answer, you need to replace the password in the hashbytes with the value you want to convert

Comment: glad it worked, just remember when using those types of functions for an insert, you use them on the values side. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO EMP_USER(PK,status,login_id,password,fk_role,last_update_ts,last_update_by,created_by)
VALUES (2,1,HASHBYTES('md5', password),'abc','abc',2,'3/15/2012 12:21:46 PM','abc','abc')
```

insert statement works like that

```
insert into table (col1, col2) values (val1, val2)
```

Put `HASHBYTES('md5', password)` in the values part and name that column in the column part

Comment: +1: The problem is that he put something else than a column name in the first line

Comment: @Java_NewBie: I don't know how the column you want to store the hashed password is named. Replace `password` with the name of that column. Example: `... EMP_USER(PK,status,login_id,password_column_name,...`